# java graphics isn't drawing anything

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

The program draws a bunch of rectangles for a bar graph. I know the bar class works perfectly fine because I've got it working before adding in the graph panel class. I was drawing straight onto the frame instead of the graph panel. I assume its a problem in the way my set visible methods are called as it was pointed out to me before. I tried looking into it but I've had no luck after playing around and reading documentation.

```
     import java.awt.Color;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphPanel extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<Bar> graphBars;
    private int nBars;

    public GraphPanel(int nBars, JFrame mainFrame) {
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.graphBars = new ArrayList<Bar>(nBars);
        this.nBars = nBars;
        this.initBars(mainFrame.getWidth());
        for(Bar b: this.graphBars) {
            this.add(b);
        }

    }

    private void initBars(int frameW) {
        Random random = new Random();
        float hue; 
        Color color; 
        int barPadding = frameW/this.nBars;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.nBars; i++) {
            hue = random.nextFloat();
            color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 0.9f, 1.0f);
            this.graphBars.add(new Bar(i*barPadding + 30, 350, color));
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Bar> getBarList() {
        return this.graphBars;
    }
}






@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Bar extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    int height = 0;
    Color barColor;
    Rectangle bar;
    private final int WIDTH = 20;
    Thread bartender;
    private Semaphore s;

    public Bar(int x, int y, Color barColor) {
        this.barColor= barColor;
        this.bar = new Rectangle(x, y, this.WIDTH, this.height);
        this.bartender= new Thread(this);
        this.s = new Semaphore(1);
    }

    public boolean setNewHeight(int h) {
        try {
            this.s.acquire();
            this.height = h;
            this.s.release();
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void update() {
        if (this.bar.height < this.height) {
            bar.reshape(this.bar.x, --this.bar.y, this.bar.width, ++this.bar.height);
        } else {
            bar.reshape(this.bar.x, ++this.bar.y, this.bar.width, --this.bar.height);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(this.barColor);
        g2d.fill(this.bar);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void callBarTender() {
        this.bartender.resume();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("sdf");
        while(true) {
            if (this.bar.height < this.height) {
                for(int i = this.bar.height; i<this.height; i++ ) {
                    try {
                        update();
                        repaint();
                        Thread.sleep(15);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (this.height < this.bar.height) {
                for(int i = this.bar.height; i>this.height; i-- ) {
                    try {
                        update();
                        repaint();
                        Thread.sleep(15);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            this.bartender.suspend();
        }
    }

}



 public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            GraphPanel gPane = new GraphPanel(3, frame);
            frame.add(gPane);

            gPane.getBarList().get(0).setVisible(true);
            gPane.getBarList().get(1).setVisible(true);
            gPane.getBarList().get(2).setVisible(true);
            gPane.setVisible(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            gPane.getBarList().get(0).setNewHeight(100);
            gPane.getBarList().get(1).setNewHeight(100);
            gPane.getBarList().get(2).setNewHeight(100);

            gPane.getBarList().get(0).bartender.start();
            gPane.getBarList().get(1).bartender.start();
            gPane.getBarList().get(2).bartender.start();
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: And [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer will take a look into those, but to my knowledge they shouldn't be the cause of this problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @jacksexton Actually, the first one is not the "cause", but your lack of understand about how the layout manager API works is...See the updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You should override `getPreferredSize` of your `GraphPanel` to ensure that they are laid out correctly
- The x/y positions you are passing to the `Bar` class are irrelevant, as this is causing your `Rectangle` to paint outside of the visible context of the `Bar` pane.  Painting is done from within the context of the component (0x0 been the top/left corner of the component)
- The use of `Rectangle` or the way you are using it, is actually causing issues.  It's impossible to know exactly how big you component will be until it's layed or painted
- There is a reason why `resume` and `suspend` are deprecated, this could cause no end of "weird" (and wonderful) issues
- Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for why you're bars aren't been updated correctly and why the x/y coordinates are pointless
- Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for an alternative to your use of `Thread`

Possibly, something more like...

[image: Bars]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                //      frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                GraphPanel gPane = new GraphPanel(3, frame);
                frame.add(gPane);

                gPane.getBarList().get(1).setFill(false);

                gPane.getBarList().get(0).start();
                gPane.getBarList().get(1).start();
                gPane.getBarList().get(2).start();

                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class GraphPanel extends JPanel {

        private ArrayList<Bar> graphBars;
        private int nBars;

        public GraphPanel(int nBars, JFrame mainFrame) {
            this.graphBars = new ArrayList<Bar>(nBars);
            this.nBars = nBars;
            this.initBars(mainFrame.getWidth());
            for (Bar b : this.graphBars) {
                this.add(b);
            }

        }

        private void initBars(int frameW) {
            Random random = new Random();
            float hue;
            Color color;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.nBars; i++) {
                hue = random.nextFloat();
                color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 0.9f, 1.0f);
                this.graphBars.add(new Bar(color));
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<Bar> getBarList() {
            return this.graphBars;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Bar extends JPanel {

        private Color barColor;
        private boolean fill = true;

        private float fillAmount = 0;
        private float delta = 0.01f;

        private Timer timer;
        private Rectangle bar;

        public Bar(Color barColor) {
            bar = new Rectangle();
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
            this.barColor = barColor;
            timer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fillAmount += isFill() ? delta : -delta;
                    //                  System.out.println(fillAmount);
                    if (fillAmount < 0) {
                        fillAmount = 0;
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    } else if (fillAmount > 1.0f) {
                        fillAmount = 1f;
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        public void setFill(boolean fill) {
            this.fill = fill;
            if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                if (fill && fillAmount == 1) {
                    fillAmount = 0;
                } else if (!fill && fillAmount == 0) {
                    fillAmount = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isFill() {
            return fill;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(20, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(this.barColor);
            int height = Math.round(getHeight() * fillAmount);
            bar.setSize(getWidth(), height);
            bar.setLocation(0, getHeight() - height);
            g2d.fill(bar);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```